# Buik update custom field values from external API

Tags: custom-field, api

I have many posts (about 1,000) where each contains a custom field with a value.  I need to update these values periodically, hopefully at least once per day, from an external API.

What is a recommended way to go about this without getting timeouts and using the most efficient means possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a WordPress cron job, in the form of a real server cron job (by default WordPress cronjobs are executed when a user visits the website).

Setting up a cron job (the easy way): https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-cron-job/

Real cronjob via server crontab: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/wordpress/wp-cron-crontab/